# How to make image upload not just from camera?

Tags: android, firebase

I have three buttons in my application. One is for a camera, second is for a gallery and the third one is to upload. I changed my upload method from web server to googles firebase. Currently, I am only able to upload from my camera button. If I try to upload from gallery button it starts searching image in a temporary folder where images are saved when they are taken by a camera.

Taking image from gallery:

```
    private void ImageSelection()
{
    Intent intent = new Intent();
    intent.setType("image/*");
    intent.setAction(Intent.ACTION_GET_CONTENT);
    startActivityForResult(intent, IMAGE_REQUEST);

}
```

On activity method:

```
        else if (requestCode == IMAGE_REQUEST && resultCode == RESULT_OK && data != null)
    {

        Uri FilePath = data.getData();
        try {

            bitmap = MediaStore.Images.Media.getBitmap(getContentResolver(), FilePath);
            mImageView.setImageBitmap(bitmap);
            mImageView.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
            mEditText.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
            staticSpinner.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);

            if (TextUtils.isEmpty(mEditText.getText())){
                mEditText.setError("Privalomas laukas");
            }

        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
```

Upload method:

```
private void UploadImage() {

    if(photoFile != null)
    {
        final ProgressDialog progressDialog = new ProgressDialog(this);
        progressDialog.setTitle("Uploading...");
        progressDialog.show();

        StorageReference ref = storageReference.child("images/"+ staticSpinner.getSelectedItem().toString().trim()+"_"+ mEditText.getText().toString());
        ref.putFile(Uri.fromFile(photoFile))
                .addOnSuccessListener(new OnSuccessListener<UploadTask.TaskSnapshot>() {
                    @Override
                    public void onSuccess(UploadTask.TaskSnapshot taskSnapshot) {
                        progressDialog.dismiss();
                        Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "Uploaded", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                        mImageView.setImageResource(0);
                        mImageView.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                        mEditText.setText("");
                        mEditText.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                        staticSpinner.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                        mCapture.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                        mChoose.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                        //mUpload.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                        photoFile = new File(String.valueOf(photoFile));
                        photoFile.delete();
                    }
                })
                .addOnFailureListener(new OnFailureListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onFailure(@NonNull Exception e) {
                        progressDialog.dismiss();
                        Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "Failed "+e.getMessage(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                        mImageView.setImageResource(0);
                        mImageView.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                        mEditText.setText("");
                        mEditText.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                        staticSpinner.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                        mCapture.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                        mChoose.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                        //mUpload.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                        photoFile = new File(String.valueOf(photoFile));
                        photoFile.delete();
                    }
                })
                .addOnProgressListener(new OnProgressListener<UploadTask.TaskSnapshot>() {
                    @Override
                    public void onProgress(UploadTask.TaskSnapshot taskSnapshot) {
                        double progress = (100.0*taskSnapshot.getBytesTransferred()/taskSnapshot
                                .getTotalByteCount());
                        progressDialog.setMessage("Uploaded "+(int)progress+"%");
                    }
                });
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Added an else if statement. Stupid me